# Scala beginner has some questions

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm going to learn Scala, I already have experience in programming. But I have some questions.

1. When I create a Project in IntelliJ there I must choose between sbt, Lightbend Project start and IDEA. What should I choose and what's the difference between them?
2. After I have created a Project, I have to create a Scala Class, right? Then I have to choose between Class, Object and Trait.
   What is the difference between them?

3.Are there any other things they are good to know?
Best regards Lockna

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The simplest thing to choose would be IDEA. IntelliJ will compile the project for you and you shouldn't have to do much to get it working. If you want to learn Scala and a popular build system at the same time, use SBT. It's going to be too much information to ingest at once though, so I wouldn't recommend it if you're an absolute beginner in Scala/functional programming.
2. Well, perhaps you should read about Scala. That's a Scala 101 question. It's already well documented on the internet, probably a thousand times, and it's not valuable to add another one here.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot

Comment: ^^ enjoy your learning

Comment: Sure, I will try xD